# how to manage SPJobDefinition.Properties using central admin SP2010?

Tags: 2010

Is it possible to manage properties for a custom job definition using central admin?

The code I have in a feature receiver sets the property like this:

```
myJobDefinition.Properties.Add("ConnectionString", "My connection string");
```

Now that the job definition is installed. I would like the administrator to be able to change this connection string property as required.

I checked Central Admin, but it seems I may have overlooked something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot configure Custom Timer Jobs from Central Admin. If you look at AC's blog posts and How To:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc427068.aspx

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686.aspx

Various options to store configuration for custom timer job is explored. I would suggest to store it via SPPersistedObject object because that does not involve web.config etc. Also, you can attach your config to a SPFarm object which is more logical for a timer job.

Below is an example:
http://www.bluedoglimited.com/SharePointThoughts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=271

As far as allowing admins to configure it, you can deploy a custom application page in the _Admin folder and have a link to it specified (via CustomAction) somehere in Central Admin.

Comment: Agreed, SPPersisted objects is the way to go. It's worth noting, the SPWebApplication object is an SPPersisted object, and it has a Properties hashtable. I've always stored settings for my jobs in that, and put a configuration page into Central Admin